# How to handle a .js extension correctly in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script.

```
while IFS= read -r filename;
  do [[ $(md5 path/to/"$filename-orig") = $(md5 path/to/"$filename") ]] || echo $filename differs;
  done < path/to/list-of-files-to-compare.txt
```

It's supposed to compare two files (by computing their MD5 hash digest) then report if they are different. It gets the files to compare from a list.

The problem is that if the file I am trying to read is at, say,

```
path/to/foo-orig.js
```

the script will look for the file at

```
path/to/foo.js-orig
```

and, obviously, this throws an error and fails.

How do I correct this bug in my script so that I handle the `.js` extension correctly?

Edit

## TL;DR:

Given a string `foo.bar` how can I get `foo-orig.bar`?

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question from the scratch to something much, much smaller along the lines of: "Given a string `foo.bar` how can I get a string `foo-orig.bar`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: Thanks for the suggestion. Does the TLDR do the job? I wanted to keep the context in case that helps, but I do see the value in making the question shorter for clarity. So thanks. Does that do the trick?

Comment: If you ask for my opinion then I suggest you very much to change your question. I see SO question as reference question which should be as short as possible and as general as possible. (That is I don't think that OPs case should matter much.) But this is just my opinion yours might be different.

Comment: On another note: I suggest you remove the reference to BASH from the title, see [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are really only asking: *Given a string `foo.bar` how can I get a string `foo-orig.bar`*? This can be done as:

```
$ f="path/to/foo.js"
$ echo "${f%.js}-bak.js"
path/to/foo-bak.js
```

It is documented under *Parameter Expansion*  in `man bash`:

> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>   Remove matching suffix pattern. The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `"%"` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `"%%"` case) deleted. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: What if the `.js` extension is variable? In other words, sometimes it might be `.md`, `.txt` or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

This example will handle all kind of extensions and even the case where there is no extension in $filename:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
   if [[ $filename =~ ^(.*)([.].*)$ ]]; then
       prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
       suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
   else
       prefix=${filename}
       suffix=''
   fi
   md5a=$(md5 -q "path/to/${prefix}-orig${suffix}")
   md5b=$(md5 -q "path/to/${filename}")
   [[ $md5a = $md5b ]] || echo $filename differs;
   unset md5a
   unset md5b
   unset prefix
   unset suffix
done < path/to/list-of-files-to-compare.txt
```

Not tested though. I just wrote it out of my head.